# Searching Java Files With Specific Import in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, shortcut

I am using eclipse as an IDE for a project. In my workspace I have lots of java files and I was just wondering if there is a way for me to search for the java files in my workspace that imports a specific library. For example, I want to search for the files that has "import java.util.*;". Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Like other IDEs, Eclipse probably has a "Find in Project" menu option that will allow you to search for any arbitrary search string (optionally case-sensitive, or whole word).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the full text search in Eclipse. Try "Search => File Search" and entering "import java.util.*" in the "containing text" field. then set the file name patterns to "*.java" and set the correct scope, click search. :)